# 'sqlpackage.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command Error

Tags: sql-server, environment-variables, sqlpackage

I used maven,Microsoft SQL server management studio 17.SQL server verion is 14.0.1000.169.
When i build my project it gives following error and build failed

> 'sqlpackage.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.
>   [ERROR] The following errors occured during execution:
>   [ERROR] 'sqlpackage.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   [ERROR] operable program or batch file.

This is my system environment path variables.
[image]

I can't find what's the wrong

Comment: Please do not add the `sql` tag to your question: there is no SQL query involved in your question. And "SQL" is not the same as "Microsoft SQL Server".

Comment: I just got the same problem. Even though my path was in the env it was saying `is not recognized...` It is case sensitive once I put `SqlLocalDB.exe` all good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's fixed using following steps.

this is because you haven't sqlpackage.exe in your Path variables.
to fix this follow below steps.

**You need to Install Sql server data tools**

For windows,

- Install chocolatey
- Install SSDT components
- Add sqlpackage.exe to classpath

**For Install chocolatey**

- https://chocolatey.org/install

**For Install SSDT components**

- choco install sqlserver-cmdlineutils
- choco install sql2014.clrtypes
- choco install sql2014-sqldom
- choco install sql2014-dacframework

**For Add sqlpackage.exe to classpath**

- RUN setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DAC\bin;"

Comment: it is not recommended to use previous version of DacFx with current version of SQL Server. I believe, previous versions of DacFx do not implement all features available in SQL Server 14.0 (2017)

Answer (score 8):

I didn't have the location of `sqlpackage.exe` in the `PATH` variable. After adding it to `PATH` variable, had resolved the issue for me. *(Something like below)*

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DAC\bin
```

Comment: For me I had just to change the version (SQL Server 2022 = 160) -> 
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\160\DAC\bin

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you havn't installed Data-tier Application Framework. You can download and install DacFx (17.4.1) from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56508

Answer (score 1):

Adding these locations into path variable will fix both maven and gradle error if you already installed mssql server 2019.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DAC\bin

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn

Answer (score 0):

Download Microsoft SQL Server **Data-Tier Application Framework** from  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56508 and open Environment settings and set the **PATH** variable to *C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DAC\bin*

Answer (score 0):

try following:

1. install https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/3.1
2. install https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage/sqlpackage-download?view=sql-server-ver15
3. run this command in terminal in projects directory(without braces) "dotnet add package Microsoft.SqlServer.DACFx"